# Unable to display <CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_ITEM_SIZE> in OpenCL and C++

Tags: c++, opencl

I am new to OpenCL and I have a problem with displaying the `<CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_ITEM_SIZES>` as a whole number/value. Instead I get a memory address.

Initially, I tried to declare a string and integer output variable to display the maximum work item size. But eventually I found out that the work item size returns a `size_t` data type instead. So I created a vector to store the size_t variable but it outputs a memory address instead.

And also, my display shows the Device Number in the reverse order (shows Device #1 then Device #0 - this is used to select a device for the later part of my program)

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<cl::Platform> platforms;    // available platforms
    std::vector<cl::Device> devices;        // devices available to a platform
    std::string outputString;               // string for output
    std::vector<::size_t> maxWorkItems[3];
    unsigned int i, j;                      // counters
    std::string choice;                     // user input choice

    cl::Platform::get(&platforms);
    std::cout << "Do you want to use a CPU or GPU device: ";
    std::cin >> choice;
    if (choice == "CPU" || choice == "cpu")
    {
        // for each platform
        for (i = 0; i < platforms.size(); i++)
        {
            // get all CPU devices available to the platform
            platforms[i].getDevices(CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL, &devices);

            for (j = 0; j < devices.size(); j++)
            {
                cl_device_type type;
                devices[j].getInfo(CL_DEVICE_TYPE, &type);
                if (type == CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CPU) {
                std::cout << "\tDevice #" << j << std::endl;
                //outputs the device type
                std::cout << "\tType: " << "CPU" << std::endl;
                // get and output device name
                outputString = devices[j].getInfo<CL_DEVICE_NAME>();
                std::cout << "\tName: " << outputString << std::endl;
                // get and output device vendor
                outputString = devices[j].getInfo<CL_DEVICE_VENDOR>();
                std::cout << "\tVendor: " << outputString << std::endl;
                //get and output compute units
                std::cout << "\tNumber of compute units: " << devices[j].getInfo<CL_DEVICE_MAX_COMPUTE_UNITS>() << std::endl;
                //get and output workgroup size
                std::cout << "\tMaximum work group size: " << devices[j].getInfo<CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_GROUP_SIZE>() << std::endl;
                //get and output workitem size
                maxWorkItems[0] = devices[j].getInfo<CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_ITEM_SIZES>();
                std::cout << "\tMaximum work item size: " << maxWorkItems << std::endl;
                //get and output local memory size
                std::cout << "\tLocal memory size: " << devices[j].getInfo<CL_DEVICE_LOCAL_MEM_SIZE>() << std::endl;
                std::cout << std::endl;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Below is the undesired output of my code:
The max work item size is in hexadecimal format, and the device numbers are in reverse order.
[image: output]

Comment: I've answered your main question in my answer, regarding the reverse device list I'm assuming it's something to do with the line `if (type == CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CPU) {`. That brace is unmatched in your code, so it wouldn't actually compile, so it's hard to say what code you're *actually* running to get that output. Perhaps you'd like to log `i` (the platform index) as well - my guess is it's platform 0, device 1 followed by platform 1, device 0 because the other devices are not CPUs.

Comment: @pmdj Ah I see. My computer has 4 devices total. Two CPU, two GPU. I'm thinking that each platform contains 1 GPU and 1 CPU device each. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_ITEM_SIZE` property is of array type, [specifically, `size_t[]`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/clGetDeviceInfo.html). You shouldn't be expecting a scalar value, but an array of `CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_ITEM_DIMENSIONS` elements. With the OpenCL C++ wrapper, you're on the right track with the `vector`, but you've now declared an array of 3 vectors:

```
std::vector<::size_t> maxWorkItems[3];
```

You in fact just want the one vector that will hold all the returned values:

```
std::vector<::size_t> maxWorkItems;
```

The property query becomes:

```
maxWorkItems = devices[j].getInfo<CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_ITEM_SIZES>();
```

Then you should be able to query the max work items in each dimension using `maxWorkItems[0]`, `maxWorkItems[1]`, etc.

Comment: It works now, I iterated the maxWorkItem vector using a for loop. I looped it for the .size() of the maxWorkItems vector.